# Django migrating from 1.3.1 to 1.7.4 and keep getting Server Error 500

Tags: python, django

This may be a silly question, but I am just a beginner of python/django. 
I keep getting Server Error (500) and Not Found page (*The requested URL / was not found on this server.*)

In my views.py, if I just test a string of “Hello, World”, then it is OK.
If I use index.html (which is in Templates folder), or the links such as register, login, etc, I have the above error.
I can see the login window of admin without static css files. When I log in I will also have Server Error 500.

I guess the problem is from the URL system of Django not working properly?

The existing project I got was built on Django 1.3.1 and I have just upgraded it to 1.7.4.
As you can see from below, the old structure of the project in django 1.3.1 is like this:

```
django 1.3.1 
server
      /node/
            admin.py, functions.py, models.py
      /templates/
                 index.html
      /static/
      /manage.py
      /settings.py
      /urls.py
```

and in 1.7.4 like this:

```
django 1.7.4
server
      /server/
              settings.py, urls.py, views.py
      /node/
            admin.py, functions.py, models.py, views.py
      /templates/
                 index.html
      /static/
      /manage.py
```

The below is the details of the project:

**functions.py**

```
@csrf_exempt
def register(request):

@csrf_exempt
def login(request):

@csrf_exempt
def forgot_password(request):
```

**models.py**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from server import views
from node.functions import *

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index_view),
    # url(r'^index/$', views.indexView),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^register/', register),
    url(r'^login/', login),
    url(r'^forgot_password/', forgot_password),
)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index_view(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, World")

def indexView(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

**settings.py**

```
import os

DEBUG = False
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

__file__ = os.getcwd()
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.normpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.example.com', '.exmaple.com.']

AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'node.UserProfile'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': 'db',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'pass',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
SITE_ID = 1
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "media")
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "static")
STATIC_URL = 'http://example.com/static/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/admin/media/'
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
SECRET_KEY = ‘xxx'

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'server.urls'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
     os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'templates'),
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'node',
    'django.contrib.gis',
)

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}

# Templates directory
REGISTRATION_TEMPLATES_DIR = 'registration/'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'node.auth_backends.CustomBackend',
)

GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = '/usr/local/lib/libgdal.so'

TEST_RUNNER = 'django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner'
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't know about 500. You can look at that by set DEBUG=True. For 404, check you settings, under TEMPLATE_LOADER

Comment: Thanks Jerry, for 404, the path in TEMPLATE_DIRS is wrong. It was supposed to be like this: /path-to/example.com/server/templates, however somehow it was /path-to/example.com/templates. Because debug=true wasn't working before, I couldn't see the error details. After I changed to os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'server/templates'), it was okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with DEBUG = True !

Server Error (500) is a backend error (logic!), DEBUG = True will says more things about the error and its solution.

Comment: At first, I was going to let you know that I tried with Debug=True before but could only see those words: "Server Error (500)", nothing more, no error details showing up, that is why I didn't know how to solve the problem without the details and posted the question here. But a moment ago I decided to dig deeper to find out why there was no error details coming up. I did change something in settings and finally the page of error details came up, and therefore the error got fixed by now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned the structure has been changed, hence you are getting this error, i would suggest you run your project built on 1.3 in a virtual env.
Thanks

Comment: It is working built on 1.3. The problem is fixed now. thanks anyway.